# UITextView becomeFirstResponder fails with iOS SDK 8.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, becomefirstresponder

I tried to make Textview **becomeFirstResponder** but it fails. It's working fine with same code with **iOS SDK 7** Don't know what's wrong with **iOS SDK 8.2.**

I am also checking `canBecomeFirstResponder` too. It passes true for this but fails and returns **NO** for `becomeFirstResponder`. Here I am doing this on viewWillAppear method and also tried in viewDidAppear Method.

**Code**

```
if([txtView canBecomeFirstResponder])
{
    temp = [txtView becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Also I have found same issues with others and they have suggested to use like below. But not working in my case with changing delay time too.

```
[txtView performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

Please suggest If I require to change anything as per new iOS SDK releases.

Comment: it does not relate to Xcode; relates to iOS SDK instead.

Comment: Just check if you have set the Delegate of txtView and IBOutlet is linked properly from XIB or Storyboard.

Comment: @Raptor Okay thanks for update. But I have added because in iOS8 also it's working fine my app store version and it was submitted with xcode 5.X

Comment: @SurajMirajkar Yes. It's delegate and IBOutlate linked properly I checked for that. Also it's working with iOS7.

Comment: Try checking if you've implemented `textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView` delegate that may prevent `textView` to become first responder

Comment: What is the issue you are facing. Is the keyboard not appearing in simulator.

Comment: @Jassi. Yes keyboard not appearing in simulator as well as in Device. And as stated in question [txtView becomeFirstResponder]; this returns me NO.

Comment: It is giving NO to me as well. But I can see the keyboard at my end. you are missing something else. Sometimes on keyboard it is hidden so it can be visible by pressing Command+K. But as you said it is not visible on device. that is weird.

Comment: @Jassi. Yes that's why I also wrote for device. Yes it's not showing keyboard too and not firing keyboard delegate method too as it's not opening..

Comment: If you can send me your code I can check it better. You can add me on skype. My id is - jasvindersingh_evontech.

Comment: @Jassi Hi.. thanks you very much for your support and you feedback but it against with my company policy :-( :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73930/discussion-between-jassi-and-niks).

Comment: let us discuss in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73930/discussion-between-jassi-and-niks

Answer (score -2):

i have used `[txtView becomeFirstResponder];` inside `viewDidLoad`. It's working fine for me.

Comment: Did you had issue like above? Means was getting issue only with latest xcode/iOS8.x?

Comment: nopes, i have used with xCode 6.1 and iOS 8.2 latest. plz explain me this line of code "temp = [txtView becomeFirstResponder];".

Comment: It's BOOL returns that becomeFirstResponder or not but I am getting NO in that variable.